# Android Contextual menu (similar to music app)

Tags: android

I would like to create a contextual menu for a listview similar to the one used by the google play music app in the listviews. (see screenshot. The triangle buttons open the menu for the album. and then one can select different options depending on the selected item.) But I've also seen this element in other apps.

https://lh5.ggpht.com/IvSpTcmdyUOC9GoX-x528xAzy9jEPjWCLcNcru4CBEcUNZ-YHo0y2TQHcGmuvOQ2zg

The Problem is that I neither know how to implement the triangle button correctly (is that just a normal imagebutton?) nor do I know how to open that popup window for each entry.

One approach I tried was using a spinner. But the problem is that the spinner always was as wide as the longest element in it and not just the triangle. Otherwise this would be a good solution. Is there a way to set the spinner to a smaller size and hide the horizontal line beneath it?

Or would a spinner be the complete wrong approach and I should solve this problem differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a Button or an ImageButton to trigger the PopupMenu. You could use [Android Holo Colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/) to create the background image. Alternatively the Holo default spinner background should do the trick, too.

When the Button is clicked you should trigger a [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu). The Android PopupMenu is for Android SDK API 11+. So if you're about to support lower versions you should consider external libraries like [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere).

The Spinner Widget is not suitable for your purpose.

Comment: The PopupMenu looks like a good solution, but it needs API level 11. :/ I actually plan on supporting from 8 upwards.

Comment: If you're supporting API 8+ you might consider the HoloEverywhere library. They backported the PopupMenu-Widget, but since their version  isn't as far as good as the original I wrote a simple backport, too. Have a look at it on github. https://github.com/Taig/PopupMenuCompat

Comment: Great! Your library seems to work perfect. (I'll mark your answer as accepted, and it would be nice if you could add a link to holoeverywhere/your library in the answer. Just to make it more obvious)

Answer (score 0):

I have not really used the Music app before, but I would try to answer the question from what I understand from the screenshot. It seems to me that options that come up are presented in a simple Dialog. This dialog has a list that can be easily implemented as given [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList).
SO, what you can do is include a `Button`, or `ImageView`, or `ImageButton` or any other `View` in the list item and clicking on that will display the dialog.